# Injection of application service in NavigationProvider

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

## Description

I have injected an application service in my project's navigation provider in order to generate dynamic data based menus.
But I faced a problem that NavigationProvider doesn't accept dependency injection to app service!

I need to access the app service function to get data from DB so I can show dynamic menu (fetched from DB).
How can I do that?

### Technical details:

- Abp package version: 5.14.0
- My base framework: .Net Core.
- Exception message and stack trace if available:

```
Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException: 'Can't create component 'Abp.AutoMapper.AutoMapperObjectMapper' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
```

[image]

- Steps needed to reproduce the problem:
  Just add any dependency injection to any application service inside `navigationprovider` .

### Update:

When I injected the Manager instead of the AppService, an exception is thrown when a function in the manager access data in DB!

`System.AggregateException: 'Object name: 'DynamicDataDbContext'.Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.`

Comment: try injecting a Manager instead of AppService

Comment: Show the full stack trace.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: When I injected the Manager instead of the AppService, that solved the problem.
Thanks @MuhammadKamranAslam

Comment: Actually, When I inject  the manager, without accessing the DB it doesn't cause any problem, but adding any function to fetch the data from DB it gave an exception!

Comment: Please share the code of NavigationManager and the Manager accessing the DB. And try to make sure proper async/await are used